# How does foreach work when looping through function results?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

Suppose I have the following code:

```
foreach(string str in someObj.GetMyStrings())
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

Will `someObj.GetMyStrings()` be called on every iteration of the loop? Would it be better to do the following instead:

```
List<string> myStrings = someObj.GetMyStrings();
foreach(string str in myStrings)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

?

Comment: Try it and see - Put a breakpoint in `GetMyStrings()` and see how many times the debugger stops there!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The function's only called once, to return an `IEnumerator<T>`; after that, the `MoveNext()` method and the `Current` property are used to iterate through the results:

```
foreach (Foo f in GetFoos())
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

is somewhat equivalent to:

```
using (IEnumerator<Foo> iterator = GetFoos().GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        Foo f = iterator.Current;
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Note that the iterator is disposed at the end - this is particularly important for disposing resources from iterator blocks, e.g.:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLines(string file)
{
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, you really want the file to be closed when you finish iterating, and the compiler implements `IDisposable` cunningly to make that work.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, But i think C# compiler does not allow you to edit the IEnumerable while the foreach loop is running.

Comment: @ShaswatRungta: I don't know what you mean by "edit the IEnumerable" or how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: If you try to Edit the IEnumerable once the foreach has started executing, the application throws an exception during run time
Try to run this code http://pastebin.com/MztPyiuA .

Comment: @ShaswatRungta: Compilers can't throw exceptions - they're not involved at execution time. And you still haven't said what you mean by "edit the IEnumerable". I suspect you're getting confused with the safeguards that *some collection types* (e.g. `List<T>`) but in place. If you modify a `List<T>` while you're iterating over it, yes, you'll get an exception. That's a decision made by the `List<T>` implementation - I don't see how it's relevant to this question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought this was because the List was processed as an IEnumerable for foreach loop and the loop was not allowing it to be edited while iterating over it.
[Used the word compiler by mistake. I meant during run time]

Comment: @ShaswatRungta: "The loop" can't detect this at all - there's nothing on `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator` to monitor changes. It's a per-collection decision. The concurrent collections *do* allow modification while iterating, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121897/discussion-between-shaswat-rungta-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 19):

No.. the function will get called once to get the IEnumerable.. and then there will be repeated call to MoveNext and Current.

Answer (score 4):

GetMyStrings() retuns an object of type IEnumerable.  The runtime knows how to deal with that.  It calls IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() and then on that enumerator object calls MoveNext() and Current.

Answer (score 3):

Just to round the question off in case you fall into a "all for's are the same";

```
for(int x=0;x < ProvideCeiling(); x++)
```

*does* call the function each time.