# Why does foreach in C# behave this way and is there a way it gets fixed in the future?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

```
long[] b = new long[1];
int i1 = b[0]; // compile error as it should

// no warning at all, large values gets converted to negative values silently
foreach (int i2 in b) 
{
}

class Customer : Person{}
Person[]p = new Person[]{mypers};

// no warning at all, throws typecastexception at runtime
foreach (Customer c in p) 
{
}
```

I know they cannot simply fix it, because it would break existing programs.

But why don't they make a compatibility option in c# compiler where I can turn on typesafe foreach block generation at least for new programs or programs where I am sure it works?

Comment: In the future, ask a question, don't hang a question on a very controversial and inflammatory rant.

Comment: You mean they should add special type conversion rules for `foreach`specifically? The problem has nothing to do with `foreach`. It is C#'s typesystem as a whole that allows certain conversions. It does so because they're useful in some cases.

Comment: Agreed, "Can foreach be fixed w/o breaking existing code" would have been a question.

Comment: For anyone curious as to my last comment, besides the question the title was previously "Why does foreach in C# suck so much?"

Comment: `foreach` isn't broken in C#. Your understanding of what it should do is. I could cause the same behavior in your single assignments by emulating what happens in the `foreach` statement: `int i1 = (int) b[0];` or `Customer c = (Customer)p[0];`. By specifying a type in the `foreach` statement, you're telling the compiler to explicitly cast each element to your desired type and it's simply listening to you.

Comment: I know that foreach automatically makes a type conversions, which is imho a bad desicion that should be fixed

Comment: Where's Eric Lippert's Bat-signal when you need it? :)

Comment: It is not a bad decission at all, it's even a very good decission. You are just using it in a wrong way

Comment: @codymanix - the bad decision is in your code, not in the compiler. You said in your foreach that you wanted longs typecast to ints. It did it. I don't see the problem. If you wanted longs in your foreach, you should have cast them to longs. -1

Comment: @Joel Etherton: Sometimes you make mistakes.

Comment: @Greg - True dat, and I've made more than my share of them. However, I never complained that the programming language was insufficient because of my errors.

Comment: Here's some online code that demonstrates the issue. Compiles fine but runtime exception thrown: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5zGgIZ.

Answer (score 17):

```
foreach (var c in p) 
{
}
```

avoids the problem nicely, doesn't it?

Comment: foreach (Person c in p) also would "solve" it, that is not the point..

Comment: You would need to add a check for `if (c is Customer)` inside in either case.

Comment: No. The "point" apparently wasn't to ask a question either. Which makes me wonder why you posted your rant on a Q&A site. My point is that the language allows you to omit the type entirely, and the compiler will just use the correct one. If the simplest solution does the right thing, why waste your time complaining that a more complex one requires a minimum of thought to get right?

Comment: @jalf Calm down.  It's a legitimate question, just poorly worded.

Comment: using "var" everywhere won't make programs easier to read.

Comment: @codymanix - Now I'm really confused. You don't want to use type inference using `var` but you also don't want the compiler to try typecasting even after you explicitly specify a different type in the `foreach` loop. What exactly do you want the behavior to be? (keep in mind that foreach can iterate over collections that have varying types as well).

Comment: @Josh: legitimate questions aren't tagged with `[rant]` as this was. @codymanix: I think `var` is perfectly readable.

Comment: To the [rant] keyword: Sadly to see that nobody here has my kind of humour...

Comment: I like to see the types Iam operating on and do not want to have the need to browse into the collection to see what kind of type it actually will return.

Comment: @codymanix, I started using var a while ago, and my code is stille very readable, without using comment. Just give your variables Logical names like: personList etc

Comment: Ah I got it. Instead of using explicit typing you use var and make the intended type part of the variable name..

Comment: @jaff: In response to your first comment, that's why the Subjective and Argumentative close reason exists.

Comment: I always type `foreach( var f in foo )` and use Resharper to "specify type explicitly" to change `var` into whatever type it is.

Comment: @R. Bernrose: and that's why I voted to close as Subjective and Argumentative before it was reopened. ;)

Answer (score 6):

`foreach` is behaving the only way it can.

When `foreach` iterates over a collection, it doesn't necessarily know anything about the types that will be returned (it could by a collection of interface implementations, or simply objects in the case of the older .NET 'bag' style collections).

Consider this example:

```
var bag = new ArrayList();
bag.Add("Some string");
bag.Add(1);
bag.Add(2d);
```

How would `foreach` behave in this instance (the collection has a string, an int, and a double)? You could force `foreach` to iterate over the most compatible type which, in this case, is Object:

```
foreach(object o in bag)
{
    // Do work here
}
```

Interestingly enough, using var will do exactly that:

```
foreach(var o in bag)
{
    // o is an object here
}
```

But the members of object won't really allow you to do anything useful.

**The only way to do anything useful is to rely on the developer to specify the exact type they want to use and then attempt to cast to that type.**

Answer (score 4):

You are at liberty to create an extension method on `IEnumerable` that is type safe:

```
public static void Each(this IEnumerable @this, Action action)
{
    if (@this == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("this");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach (TElement element in @this)
    {
        action(element);
    }
}
```

It is subtly different to the foreach loop and will occur additional overhead, but will ensure type safety.

Comment: I've never seen the @ before, potentially stupid question but what's that do?

Comment: @AndyC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c

Comment: @ allows you to use a C# keyword as a variable name.  So you can do questionable things like:
int @foreach = 1;
long @if = 2;
string @class = "foo";

Comment: You can use keywords as normal variables with the @ sign. normally you use it when interoperating with other languages which expose members that is a keyword in the other language.

Comment: It is simply added to let you use a reserved word as a variable name.

Comment: Cheers guys, never knew that!

Answer (score 1):

As for the why:

Using arrays, the compiler in fact translates the foreach statement into something that looks like the following.

```
private static void OriginalCode(long[] elements)
{
    foreach (int element in elements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}

private static void TranslatedCode(long[] elements)
{
    int element;
    long[] tmp1 = elements;
    int tmp2 = 0;

    while (tmp2 < elements.Length)
    {
        // the cast avoids an error
        element = (int)elements[tmp2++];
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the generated cast avoids the runtime error and of course leads to the semantic error in your case.

Btw, the same goes for IEnumerable and foreach which translates into the following code leading to the same behaviour and problem.

```
private static void OriginalCode(IEnumerable<long> elements)
{
    foreach (int element in elements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}

private static void TranslatedCode(IEnumerable<long> elements)
{
    int element;
    IEnumerator<long> tmp1 = elements.GetEnumerator();

    try
    {
        while (tmp1.MoveNext())
        {
            element = (int)tmp1.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        (tmp1 as IDisposable).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that foreach gets translated into an simple if-statement. Maybe you mean a for-statement :)

Comment: I have posted an answer before comparing while, for, foreach, and goto to the point that they will all compile to the same IL.  See it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447559/c-does-function-get-called-for-each-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop/2447646#2447646

Comment: @codymanix Ops sorry, should be a while loop :) corrected

Comment: @Matthew Whited: Indeed, the IL is pretty much the same for a lot of statement blocks. I have choosen the while loop for demonstration because I think it's the easiest way to show the cast.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Clarified and corrected based on codymax's comment

Based on my interpretation of  section 8.8.4 in the [C# Spec](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e&displaylang=en) foreach is expanded as as below. (See the part that begins "If the type X of expression is an array type then there is an implicit reference conversion from X to the System.Collections.IEnumerable interface.."

<strike>The first case converts values above int.MaxValue to -1. This is because [operations don't throw overflow by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c/2056457#2056457) .</strike>
Since the first case the conversion is in an unchecked context section 7.6.12 describes what's supposed to happen which is

> the result is truncated by discarding
>   any high-order bits that do not fit in
>   the destination type.

The second does as expected throw a runtime InvalidCastException. This is probably because the type returned by Enumerator.Current. There's probably a section that describes this but I didn't look for it.

```
        long[] b = long[0] ;


        System.Collections.IEnumerator le = ((long[])(b)).GetEnumerator();

        int i2;
        while (le.MoveNext())
        {
            i2 = (int)(long)le.Current;

        }




        Person[] p = new Person[1] { mypers };

        System.Collections.IEnumerator e = ((Person[])(p)).GetEnumerator();

        Customer c;
           while (e.MoveNext())
           {
               c = (Customer)(Person)e.Current;

            }
```

Comment: Firstly it is wrong that values above int.MaxValue are converted to -1, they convert to the corresponding negative value instead.
Secondly, foreach on arrays does *not* create a GetEnumerator call but instead a simple for-loop.
Besides, the double-cast to Person and then to Customer is superfluous.

Comment: @codymax You're right about the conversion so I updated my answer. Why do you think it doesn't do a GetEnumerator? The double cast may be superfluous in some cases but perhaps not in all.