# Is this emitted code useful?

Tags: c#, .net, ilspy

While looking through some dll's with ILSpy I came across the following code:

```
void RenderFiles(List<List<string>> pdfFiles)
{
  int num;
  for (int i = 0; i < pdfFiles.Count; i = num + 1)
  {
    // ....
    num = i;
  }
}
```

The introduction of the num variable seems strange to me. Why would the compiler introduce an extra local variable?

The original code is just a simple loop, although it uses a count variable and not a foreach enumerator:

```
void RenderFiles(List<List<string>> pdfFiles)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < pdfFiles.Count; i++)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: why downvote and close vote? this is not an opinion based question...

Comment: ILSpy is not the best decompiler. I find that Reflector produces cleaner results. Decompilation is not exact. The decompiler guesses what the source was.

Comment: Did you verify that the extra variable is actually present in the CIL? This could just be a 'feature' of the decompiler.

Comment: num is not referenced anywhere else

Comment: I would recommend Jetbrains [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). Best free decompiler i can think of.

Comment: what is the IL? that's the important bit here. The decompiled stuff is usually a red herring

Comment: @Csharpie Dotpeek just shows the loop as it originally was. I always thought any decompiler would show the IL as it was. But it was indeed a red herring.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Was this assembly in Debug or Release? BTW, it is not 100% possible to decompile code back to the original source.  Some assumptions are made and those assumptions are based on what each decompiler/compiler vendors decides.  

Here is a really old example of some code that all compiled into the same IL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447559/c-sharp-does-function-get-called-for-each-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop/2447646#2447646