# How to save stream result in a folder with showing a dialog box?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application i have to save the result in the form of a text file in a folder.My code is

```
 using (HttpWebResponse result = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {    
                    using (Stream stream = result.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", "result." + GetExtension(exportFormat)));

                        var length = copyStream(stream, Response.OutputStream);
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

When this code is executed a dialog box is shown which has save and cancel options in it.

But the problem is that i have to save the result in a specific folder in the form of text file (which is obtained from this code in dialog) without showing the dialog box.

Comment: You can't. What if I could make a site overwrite files without consent? Just put a note on the page explaining the user where to save the file.

Comment: actually the file is needed by the server in further processing.

Comment: Then save the file on the server.

Comment: how to save the file on server ? text is returned by a method GetTextFromImage(string filePath)

Comment: For example using a StreamWriter.

Answer (score 0):

It's your browser that is popping up that dialogue box.

Try forcing the content disposition header to .txt:

Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"file.txt\"

(On phone, not tested)

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming it's the list of found files you're wanting to save to a text file, how about this on your save event (rough code so not extensively tested)?

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\files.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        foreach (string item in lstFilesFound.Items)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Try Dis..

Comment: If you [copy an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120668/how-to-write-a-text-file-from-this-output), at least link to it.