# Is it a waste of time to call a function in the foreach definition?

Tags: vb.net, loops, iteration

Sometimes I have to run a loop where the list or array comes from a function.

I usually do it this way :

```
Dim list = SomeClass.GetMyList()
For Each item in list
  'Do some stuff
Next
```

Is it the same as :

```
For Each item in SomeClass.GetMyList()
  'Do some stuff
Next
```

I usually do the first way because I think that second way makes a call everytime it starts the next iteration, therefore wasting some time.

Am I right to think that way ? Or can I go ahead with second way as the compiler is smart enough not to make a call every round ?

Comment: In VB only once, in C# every time. Just print out something in that function, you'll see it will be called once.  * Sorry, I made the mistake between FOR and FOR EACH, I'm not sure about the behavior of for each in C#

Comment: The two methods are equivalent. You can easily test this by using a breakpoint or debug output from your `SomeClass.GetMyList()`.

Comment: @the_lotus - C# will also only do it once. See, for instance *[How does foreach work when looping through function results?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1632810/1364007)*

Comment: In any case, it makes little sense to be discussing anything about C# given that this is a VB question.  ;)

Comment: it took you more time to ask than to test it yourself

Comment: Although it works, I personally find it way easier to read when looking at someone else's code when done in way No. 1.

Comment: Agree: "whatever you decide to do, make it *abundantly clear."* Speed or Efficiency is probably an irrelevant consideration.

Comment: What kind of Type is the result of "GetMyList()"  -array? list? whatever..

Comment: A now-removed Answer referred to the possibility of "iterators." If the function *is* an iterator, be sure to call it in just the way that the documentation prescribes.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I thought an iterator would make a difference here but after posting I tried it out and it appears that the compiler is smart enough to only iterate over what is needed is both of the scenarios above so I deleted it

Comment: Yep, I thought that might be the case.

Comment: In some cases, there might be some differences. See [Does foreach automatically call Dispose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982396/does-foreach-automatically-call-dispose). I suppose same thing apply for VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method #1** leaves you with a reference to the list in the scope of the rest of the method.

**Method #2** creates a variable behind the scenes referencing the list, but that variable is out of scope after the for loop

For scoping I would prefer #2, but I am also impartial to succinct code. If `GetMyList` returns a reference type such as a `List<T>` or array, this could leave the door open to some unintended side effects.

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim someClass As New SomeClass()
    ' this variable stays in scope after the following For Each loop
    Dim list = someClass.GetMyList()
    For Each item In list
        Console.Write(item)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    ' now we can sort the backing field - did you intend for this to happen?
    list.Sort()
    ' the following For Each loop doesn't leave any reference behind
    For Each item In someClass.GetMyList()
        Console.Write(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Class SomeClass
    Private _list As List(Of Integer) = {3, 2, 1}.ToList()
    Public Function GetMyList() As List(Of Integer)
        Return _list
    End Function
End Class
```

Foo() writes:

> 321
>
> 123

So you can actually manipulate the backing field after you were supposedly done with it!

Comment: Yep, it's always good to use the minimal possible scope, and nice example of the potential pitfalls. +1

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm aware of the debugger but was wondering about side effects also. This is one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Only what is **within** the `for` block gets repeated, not its initialiser.

Your 2nd option does the same as the 1st, just with an unnamed temporary variable holding the result of `GetMyList()`. If anything, it might be *more* efficient for that reason... though a good optimiser would make both pieces of code equivalent anyway.

As mentioned in the comments, a debugger would've made this abundantly clear, and is an invaluable tool for countless other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

let take a simple example

there is not much information, i will assume `GetMyList` is a `list(of integer)`

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        test1()
        test2()

        Console.ReadKey(False)
    End Sub

    Sub test1()
        Dim list = SomeClass.GetMyList()
        For Each item In list
            Console.WriteLine(item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub test2()
        For Each item In SomeClass.GetMyList()
            Console.WriteLine(item)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module

Class SomeClass
    Public Shared Function GetMyList() As List(Of Integer)
        Dim aList = New List(Of Integer)

        aList.Add(1)
        aList.Add(2)
        aList.Add(3)

        Console.WriteLine("I am in the function now")

        Return aList
    End Function
End Class
```

you can run it yourself to see the behavior

now let look at the actual IL (compiled with debug)

test1 code;

```
.method public static 
    void test1 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2120
    // Code size 64 (0x40)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> list,
        [1] int32 item,
        [2] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32> VB$t_struct$L0,
        [3] bool VB$CG$t_bool$S0
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> ConsoleApplication1.SomeClass::GetMyList()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: nop
    .try
    {
        IL_0008: ldloc.0
        IL_0009: callvirt instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
        IL_000e: stloc.2
        IL_000f: br.s IL_0021
        // loop start (head: IL_0021)
            IL_0011: ldloca.s VB$t_struct$L0
            IL_0013: call instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::get_Current()
            IL_0018: stloc.1
            IL_0019: ldloc.1
            IL_001a: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
            IL_001f: nop
            IL_0020: nop

            IL_0021: ldloca.s VB$t_struct$L0
            IL_0023: call instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::MoveNext()
            IL_0028: stloc.3
            IL_0029: ldloc.3
            IL_002a: brtrue.s IL_0011
        // end loop

        IL_002c: nop
        IL_002d: leave.s IL_003e
    } // end .try
    finally
    {
        IL_002f: ldloca.s VB$t_struct$L0
        IL_0031: constrained. valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>
        IL_0037: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
        IL_003c: nop
        IL_003d: endfinally
    } // end handler

    IL_003e: nop
    IL_003f: ret
} // end of method Module1::test1
```

test2 code;

```
.method public static 
    void test2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x217c
    // Code size 62 (0x3e)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 item,
        [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32> VB$t_struct$L0,
        [2] bool VB$CG$t_bool$S0
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: nop
    .try
    {
        IL_0002: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> ConsoleApplication1.SomeClass::GetMyList()
        IL_0007: callvirt instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
        IL_000c: stloc.1
        IL_000d: br.s IL_001f
        // loop start (head: IL_001f)
            IL_000f: ldloca.s VB$t_struct$L0
            IL_0011: call instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::get_Current()
            IL_0016: stloc.0
            IL_0017: ldloc.0
            IL_0018: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
            IL_001d: nop
            IL_001e: nop

            IL_001f: ldloca.s VB$t_struct$L0
            IL_0021: call instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::MoveNext()
            IL_0026: stloc.2
            IL_0027: ldloc.2
            IL_0028: brtrue.s IL_000f
        // end loop

        IL_002a: nop
        IL_002b: leave.s IL_003c
    } // end .try
    finally
    {
        IL_002d: ldloca.s VB$t_struct$L0
        IL_002f: constrained. valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>
        IL_0035: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
        IL_003a: nop
        IL_003b: endfinally
    } // end handler

    IL_003c: nop
    IL_003d: ret
} // end of method Module1::test2
```

only thing different is when the `GetMyList` reference is called / loaded in memory

first one load it in a local variable, the second one just load it when the loop start

so both scenario will do the same thing.